# Creating range from two strings containing cell names in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have two strings s1 and s2 which contain cell names C1 and C2

```
s1 = "C1"
s2 = "C2"
```

I want create a range from these two strings

```
Set range1 = s1& ":" &s2
```

I get an error saying expected end of statement. How can this be done in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Set statement to

```
Set range1 = Range(s1 & ":" & s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set range1 = s1& ":" &s2
```

just put spaces around the & operator, otherwise with the syntax you had, it has another interpretation by the compiler.

```
Set range1 = s1 & ":" & s2
```

But this, however only assigns a string variable, and you will have another error because you should not use "Set" with a string variable (it is a built-in type in VB, not a class). if range1 is to be a string variable, remove the Set keyword. If range1 is to be a range of some sheet, use:

```
Set range1 = someSheet.Range(s1 & ":" & s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, `Range` will also take start and end addresses as separate arguments like so:

```
Set range1 = Range(s1, s2)
```